# How to find the address location of variables in C?

Tags: c

I have written a program that defines 3 `int` variables, and printed them out using `%p` format specifier.
The output is as follows:

```
0000000000000001
0000000000000002
0000000000000003
```

My question is now how do I figure out where in memory these variables are stored. Since I'm using the %p format specifier, are the outputs already the addresses in memory where variables are stored?

Here is my code:

```
int main(void)
{
   int iX1 = 1;
   int iX2 = 2;
   int iX3 = 3;

   printf("%p\n", iX1);
   printf("%p\n", iX2);
   printf("%p\n", iX3);

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Heard of the "address-of" operator `&`?

Comment: use the `&` ("address-of") operator (and convert to `void*` type): `printf("%p\n", (void*)&iX1);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%p` is only the format specifier for the data you provide.

To get the address of a variable use the `&` operator like this:

```
#include <stdio.h> // printf
#include <stdlib.h> // EXIT_SUCCESS

int main(void)
{
   int iX1 = 1;
   int iX2 = 2;
   int iX3 = 3;

   printf("%p\n", (void*){&iX1});
   printf("%p\n", (void*){&iX2});
   printf("%p\n", (void*){&iX3});


   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

```
0x7ffee4f7e8e8
0x7ffee4f7e8e4
0x7ffee4f7e8e0
```

Comment: to be safe you must cast the addresses to `void*`

Comment: Damn it, that was such a rookie mistake. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is it normal that the adress values change after every restart of the program?

Comment: @marco-a `int*` to `void*` is fine (that's why I used a compound literal rather than a more aggressive  cast in the edit), but compilers aren't obligated to parse format strings and if they don't they can't know an `int*` to `void*` conversion needs to happen in the argument. (Matching `int*` with `"%p"` is kind of a benign instance of undefined behavior though. Practically (flat memory archs) even an `int*` argument corresponding to `"%p"` will work without messing up codegen or causing weird runtime behavior.)

Comment: @Smokus Yes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization is a common security feature in OSs.

Comment: What's the benefit to the `{}` around `&iX1`?   `(void*)&iX1` seems like the straightforward and obvious thing to recommend to beginners who are new to C syntax.  (In practice on all(?) current mainstream machines, `%p` happens to work with `int*` because it has the same object-representation as `void*` on normal machines. So people who wrote `printf("%p\n", &iX1)` won't be searching on this question in the first place.)

Comment: I don't know, @PetrSkocik made that edit. Mentioned him so maybe he can answer your question.

Comment: @PeterCordes @Marco On it. 1. Q: Why cast to `void*` given that pointers usually have the same object representation anyway? A:  to satisfy language pedants. The standard says that for `%p`, "The corresponding argument *shall* be a pointer to a pointer to void.". If you don't cast, language pedants on SO tend to scream at you and chances are they can make the compiler scream too. Also failure to cast technically brings you undefined-behavior (anything-can-happen) land.

Comment: @PeterCordes 2. Q: Why "cast" thru compound literals rather than directly? A: Just a general stylistic preference, because it tends to be gentler & it is hardly any more verbose. Casts are very powerful & can be dangerous, particularly when casting between pointer types. Conversions through compound type literals are much less powerful (e.g., can add const to target, but it won't convert between wildly different pointer types unless a void* is involved). Only the `#include <stdlib.h>` part of the edit was essential. The `void*` casts satisfy pedantic correctness. `(void*){}` is personal style.